# How to make multidimensional array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to make a multidimensional array from mysql database 
Like

I have three table

```
            Table1                          Table3      
|   ID  |   GPN |   PKGID   |           |   GPN |   Amt |
|   1   |   A   |   PKG01   |           |   A   |   10  |
|   2   |   B   |   PKG02   |           |   A   |   15  |
|   3   |   C   |   PKG03   |           |   A   |   20  |
|   4   |   D   |   PKG04   |           |   A   |   25  |
                                        |   A   |   30  |
                                        |   B   |   17  |
-----------------------------           |   D   |   90  |
                                        |   B   |   20  |
        Table2                          |   B   |   40  |
|   GPN |   Date        |               |   D   |   60  |
|   A   |   2016-09-10  |               |   B   |   80  |
|   A   |   2016-09-18  |               |   B   |   100 |
|   B   |   2016-09-10  |               |   C   |   3   |
|   B   |   2016-09-11  |               |   C   |   6   |
|   B   |   2016-09-12  |               |   C   |   9   |
|   C   |   2016-10-12  |               |   C   |   12  |
|   C   |   2016-10-13  |               |   C   |   15  |
|   C   |   2016-10-14  |               |   D   |   7   |
|   D   |   2016-09-10  |               |   D   |   10  |
|   D   |   2016-10-13  |               |   D   |   13  |
```

How i have to make a multidimensional array

For Example

Date =  2016-09-10

I have to get all the from above three table behalf of given date.

so the result will be this

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [PKGID] => PKG01
            [GPN] => A
            [AMT] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 20
                    [3] => 25
                    [4] => 30
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PKGID] => PKG02
            [GPN] => B
            [AMT] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 40
                    [3] => 60
                    [4] => 80
                    [5] => 100
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PKGID] => PKG04
            [GPN] => D
            [AMT] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 90
                    [1] => 60
                    [2] => 7
                    [2] => 10
                    [2] => 13
                )
        )
)
```

I am using php and mysql.

Is there any easiest **mysql query** to do that witch i have to execute one time because right now i am executing **mysql query** multiple time in loop to making that array

Comment: trivial solution would be using group_concat in the query and exploding later when fetching

Comment: group_concat how to do that sir

Comment: Table2 appears to be irrelevant to the output you're trying to get.

Comment: Table2 here i have to check how many GPN on that day

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is

```
$arr = array();
while($row = fetch()) {
   $arr[$row['key1']][$row['key2']][etc...][] = $row;
}
```

Just use whatever fields you want to key your array off AS keys while building the array.

Comment: Sir What will be mysql query

Comment: ^ ... the plot thickens, as it were.

Comment: Yes your are right @MarcB but by posting this question i want to know easiest **mysql query** witch i have to execute one time because right now i am executing  **mysql query** multiple time in loop to making that array. and i am still learning sir as @ bwoebi is suggested me about  **group_concat** i am reading about that and other similar function. i am concentrating to not to post rubbish kind of question.